# Android Webview.scrollTo not updating (Java)

Tags: java, android, android-webview

My problem is,
that only after `testScroll()` is done the calls for the `scrollTo()` function are applied,
which results in one large jump.

Therefore, I'm unable to create bitmaps of different regions that would lie next to each other. I'm kinda clueless how to approach this issue?

What I tried so far:

I tried to interlace it in other functions in hopes of triggering it.

Sadly, `scrollTo()` will only trigger after all man made control structures are done.

I tried following the documentation,
but there is no source code and there is nothing meaningful written there.

I tried to follow it in debug mode, but that didn't bear any fruits,
be course you are limited how far you can follow along.

```
public void testScroll(View view){
        WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webViewMain);
        int xValue = webView.getScrollX();
        int yValue = webView.getScrollY();
        int scrollValue = webView.getHeight();
        
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            yValue += scrollValue;
            makeBitmapOfScreen();
            webView.scrollTo(xValue, yValue); 
        }

    }
```

Comment: The "scrollTo" method doesn't really work in the same frame, it works on the next frame. You can wrap the `makeBitmapOfScreen()` and `webView.scrollTo` calls into `webView.post()`. That should allow you to catch all frames and properly process them. If it works, let me know so I can post it as an answer.

Comment: @FurkanYurdakul sadly the suggested change is not fixing the mentioned issue.
I can't see a difference in the produced results with the change and without it.
I still only get 2 Output files instead of 10.